# Array of struct within struct (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am trying to set up an array of structs within a struct in C. The size of the array is not known until runtime, so I have tried to define the array as dynamic. I have reduced my problem to the code shown below (there are a few more members in each struct, but don't pose a problem).

```
//struct definitions
struct intStream {
int test;
};

struct io {
struct inStream **inputStream;
};

// then proceed to main
int numDevices = 4; //(derived from number of devices found at runtime)
struct io *devices;
devices->inputStream = malloc(sizeof(struct inStream) * numDevices)

// Fails on
devices->inputStream[0]->test = 1;
```

I am still relatively new to C style programming, so my understanding of memory is not complete, but through some searching I have not been able to find alternate solutions to my problem besides the struct hack which aesthetically I do not like, as well as wanting the option to include more arrays in future.

Comment: You have an unitialised variable `devices`. What do you think it is pointing at?

Comment: Please do not add answer to the question, thanks. :)

Comment: @n.m. I have been shown the error of my ways ;) not too sure what I expected looking back!

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sure, I just wanted to include a "fuller" version of the answer, thanks.

Comment: There is no array of structs in your code. Nor is there an array of **pointers to struct** in your struct. If you need a flexible array, use a _flexible array member_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, `devices` is uninitialized. Using uninitialized memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make `devices` point to some valid memory before you can dererefence that pointer.

That said,

```
 devices->inputStream = malloc(sizeof(struct inStream) * numDevices)
```

also looks wrong. What you may want is

```
 devices->inputStream = malloc(sizeof(struct inStream *) * numDevices);
```

and then, you need to allocate memory to each `devices->inputStream[i]`, also.

---

[Modified code by OP, removed from question and added into the answer, just for reference]

```
struct io *devices;
devices = malloc(sizeof(*devices));  

devices->inputStream = malloc(sizeof(struct inStream *) * numDevices);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
    devices->inputStream[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct inStream));  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, makes perfect sense in the way you explained. I tried to put in a full form answer in this comment but it didnt work, so I have updated the question with your advice/solution too.

Comment: @user2142136 I have corrected and added your code in my answer itself, hope that's ok. :)